# Is Bridge Pattern Suitable Here?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a **Model** class and an abstract **Item** class in my problem domain. A Model object contains a list of **Item** objects. Each Item object has three jobs to do:

1. Read from/write to Excel files.
2. Read from/write to binary files.
3. Read from/write to hardware.

Due to some reasons, I would like to put these three jobs in three separate class instead of putting them all together in **Item** subclass, and each **Item** subclass has different implementation for these three jobs.

The link below is UML class diagram of my current design. As the Item subclasses grow, there will be more **ItemXXXHandler_X**. It seems there should be a better design.

http://i57.tinypic.com/6epshg.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Bridge pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge) could be applied here. Seems like you have enough complexity, that can evolve independently. Still in your current design you'll have to introduce some abstraction in order to achieve all this. I see that the [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is your primary goal, but there are other principles that you could apply. [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) will be a perfect fit in your Model, since the Bridge actually enforces it. Another candidate could be a [separated Interface](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html):

[image]

In a way you can aim at [plugin architecture](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/cxx/plugin-architecture/), that could look like this:

[image]